# How to create a horizontal line that divides the View into two equal sides in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a small RN project and encountered the need to make a horizontal line in the middle inside a View element. I would like to create a View element that is divided into two equal halves horizontally.
I know it is doable in HTML && CSS using ::before and ::after tags in CSS, but how is this done in RN?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flexbox` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox):

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 0.5,
          borderBottomColor: 'black',
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
        }}
      />
</View>
```

The outer view in this example takes up the full height by setting `flex` to `1`. If you create a view inside this outer view that is half the size of the outer view and give it a `borderBottomWidth` of 1, you create a horizontal line in the middle of the outer view.

Depending on how large you want your outer view to be, you can experiment with the `flex` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 0.5,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          alignself: 'stretch'
        }}
      />
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 0.5,
          backgroundColor: 'blue'
          alignself: 'stretch'
        }}
      />
</View>
```